# Updating more than 1 db column in an UPDATE SET statement using psycopg2

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I try to update one table based on values found in another table. The following works:

```
UPDATE table1 SET col1 = ( SELECT col1 from table2 WHERE table2.col1 = table1.col1 );
```

I want to do the same using several columns. I thought the following should bring the desired result"

```
UPDATE table1 SET (col1, col2) = ( SELECT col1, col2 from table2 WHERE table2.col1 = table1.col1 );
```

but I get a

```
syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: UPDATE table1 SET (col1, col2) = ( SELECT col1, col2 f...
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
update table1 t1
set col1 = t2.col1, 
  col2 = t2.col2
from table2 t2
where t1.col1 = t2.col1;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f4940/2)

With that said, no need to update `col1 = t2.col1`  since that is your `join` criteria.